Why does event.stopPropagation() not prevent a parent directive's @HostListener from receiving click events in Angular?
I'm building an Angular application and have a custom button component that uses a directive to throttle click events. Even when the button is disabled, clicking it still triggers the function associated with the click event in the parent directive.
Here's a simplified version of my setup:
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  template: `
    <button [disabled]="isDisabled" (click)="onClick($event)">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </button>
  `,
})
export class ButtonComponent {
  @Input() isDisabled = false;
  @Output() click = new EventEmitter<Event>();

  onClick(event: Event) {
    if (this.isDisabled) {
      event.stopImmediatePropagation()
    } else {
      this.click.emit(event);
    }
  }
}

import { Directive, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[throttledClick]',
})
export class ThrottledClickDirective {
  @Output() throttledClick = new EventEmitter<Event>();
  private isThrottled = false;

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  handleClick(event: Event) {
    if (!this.isThrottled) {
      this.isThrottled = true;
      this.throttledClick.emit(event);
      setTimeout(() => this.isThrottled = false, 200);
    }
  }
}

<app-button
  throttledClick
  [isDisabled]="isButtonDisabled"
  (throttledClick)="onThrottledClick()">
  Click Me
</app-button>

When isButtonDisabled is true, the button is disabled, but clicking it still triggers the onThrottledClick() method. I expected that event.stopPropagation() in the button component would prevent the click event from reaching the directive, but it doesn't.

I think you have a misconception about event bubbling. stopPropagation() only prevents the event to bubble to the parent element. However in this case, you are listening to the same event twice, once in the component and once in the directive.

@Rahul issue is not reproducible stackblitz

@JSONDerulo Sorry i used event.stopImmediatePropagation() and updated the snippet.
